# How to store MySQL warnings in database?

Tags: mysql, logging, warnings, show

I'd like to store warnings caused by some SQL statements in the database. E.g. after

```
mysql> select 1/0;
+------+
| 1/0  |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+---------------+
| Level | Code | Message       |
+-------+------+---------------+
| Error | 1365 | Division by 0 |
+-------+------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'd like to save what SHOW WARNINGS says to some persistent table, to be able to analyze it in future.

Let's assume I know when there is something to log - I can check if  `@@warning_count > 0`.

Comment: Are you looking to do this at the database level or for a specific application?

Comment: At database level, in stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this within a stored procedure by analyzing the diagnostics. For example, the following handler for warnings could be declared by the following

```
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING 
  BEGIN 
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
         @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @message = MESSAGE_TEXT
    ;

    /* select the following into your debugging table */
    SELECT @errno, @sqlstate, @message;
  END;
```

More information about DIAGNOSTICS can be found here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/get-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this enough http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-warnings ?
Perhaps you can parse the error.log and store the warnings in a database if that is what you are after.